# innerHTML image not showing

Tags: javascript, html

I am customizing an html5 video player. I was looking to display different png's depending on the state of the video, if it is playing or not. This is the script I use but I can't get the images to show.

```
window.onload = function() {

var video = document.getElementById("video");

var playButton = document.getElementById("play-pause");

playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (video.paused == true) {
        video.play();

        playButton.innerHTML = "<img='pause.png'/>";
    } else {
        video.pause();
        playButton.innerHTML = "<img='play.png'/>";
    }
});

}
```

The HTML

```
    <div id="video-container">
<video id="video">
        <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="video.ogg" type="video/ogg">
      </video>
    <!-- Video Controls -->
    <div id="video-controls">
        <button type="button" id="play-pause" class="play"></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone spot the error?

Thank you :)

Comment: can you put your html for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well first of all you are missing the src attribute on the img tags.

```
<img='pause.png'/>
```

should be:

```
<img src='pause.png'/>
```

and same goes for the other image.

Comment: whoops... that was embarrassing.. thanks wired_in

Comment: np we've all missed stuff like that before :)